# 'T' in LocalDateTime not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

So I have two applications. One producing to an AMQ broker, the other is consuming from AMQ.

I have the DTO defined in my consuming app in which the producing app has access to this DTO too:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MemberDTO implements Serializable, AuditDTO
{

   private final String member;
   @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
   @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
   private final LocalDateTime timestamp;


}
```

The problem is that the consuming side is thorwing this exception:
`Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-04-27 10:42:09' could not be parsed at index 10`.

When I'm printing out the object just before I'm about to send using `jsmtemplate.convertAndSend(...)`, i can see it's this:
`MemberDTO(member=BOB, timestamp=2021-04-27T10:46:42.105403)`

But when I look in the Artemis broker, it seems that the timestamp field changes to `2021-04-27 10:42:09` hence why on the consuming side it's unable to parse it since it's missing the `T`?

This is the message converter im using on the producing side:

```
      MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
      converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
      converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
      converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper()
//                                   .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
//                                                  .registerModule(new Jdk8Module()));
                                                  .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()));
```

Some people are finding it hard to what i'm trying to say so the bottomline:
Why is the consuming app throwing an exception when it's attempting to build the object once it's consumed from AMQ?

Comment: Your JsonFormat has a space where the T should be. Change it to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`. (I've added this as a comment rather than an answer, as I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. I'll convert it to an answer if it works for you.)

Comment: What output do you want to achieve?

Comment: (Note that if you want subsecond precision, you'd need to adjust the format for that, too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I get `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unknown pattern letter: T]` when I add the 'T'

@SikorskyS60 I'm trying to get the object to be generated on the consuming side with localdatetime having the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: @bootlover123: Did you include it in single quotes, as per my comment?

Comment: @bootlover123: Why do you want it *without* the T, if that's giving you problems? Your question is pretty unclear. If you really want it without the T (i.e. as it is now) then you need to change the consuming code, which you haven't shown us at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I haven't been able to get it WITH the T. Which is where I'm basing my assumption that if the T is present then it'll work.

Comment: So why did you say "I'm trying to get the object to be generated on the consuming side with localdatetime having the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"? That's a format *without* the T. And surely you're generating on the producing side, and consuming on the consuming side. At this point I'm afraid I'm finding the question too confusing to help you.

Comment: Holy god, I was ready to reply, then saw the name JonSkeet. :D

Comment: @bootlover123 what is the jackson version that you have on your consumer side?